# The best way to set up a webpack config with multiple entry points

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have react application and I want to configure webpack.config. There are /src directory and it has some .js files and folder with another components, something like this:

```
src/
   /Folder with another components 
   1.js
   2.js
   3.js
```

I want to have build for 1.js, 2.js, 3.js files, which will exclude this directory from build - "Folder with another components", but also I want to have separate build for "Folder with another components". What is best way to do this?
Thank you for any helping.

Comment: Could you just setup multiple config files? Then just use the corresponding file for the builds.

Comment: Can I import source file from "Folder with another components " without build, but it has dependencies in pakage.json?